# Django 1.7 : inheritance and migration

Tags: python, django, inheritance, migration

In a **Django 1.7** application.

I want to **add inheritance** on a class and **migrate** primary keys from MyChild to MyParent class.

Before inheritance:

```
class Mychild(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

After inheritance :

```
class Mychild(MyParent):
        field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class MyParent(models.Model):
        field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Automatic migration does not work so I tried to do it manually.

```
def migration(apps, schema_editor):
    for child in MyChild.objects.all():
        parent = MyParent(id=child.pk,field2=child.field2)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('mychild', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            migration,
        ),
    ]
```

I got this error when I try to migrate it.

*django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column mychild.myparent_ptr_id does not exist
LINE 1: ..."mychild" INNER JOIN "myparent" ON ( "mychild...*

I think that my migration function does not work and that I need to add manually the field which permit to link Mychild and MyParent (perhaps a models.OneToOneField).

Sorry for bad-english. Good day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not advisable to employ inheritance like you did, because it creates plenty of join tables. If there are not many common fields in models, then you'd better just replicate them in code. If you still want to use inheritance, then you'd better use django abstract model, which doesn't create tables neither for joins nor for parents (only for derived classes):

```
class MyParent(models.Model):
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Mychild(MyParent):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I think that could solve you problems with migrations.

Comment: I just change foreign key which references MyParent in GenericForeignKey. It works. Thank you.